# emacs markdown-mode no <pre> tag for inline code

Tags: emacs, markdown

I would like the following markdown code:

````
``` 
def hello_world(self):    
print "hello world!" 
```
````

To be exported by `M-x markdown-export` as:

```
<pre><code> def hello_world(self):    
     print "hello world!" 
</code></pre>
```

Instead, `M-x markdown-export` results in:

```
<p><code> def hello_world(self):    
     print "hello world!" 
</code></p>
```

Is there a solution for this in emacs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is no Emacs problem, presuming you are referring to [Jason Blevins' Markdown Mode](http://jblevins.org/projects/markdown-mode/).

This mode does not export HTML by itself.  It simply passes the buffer contents to the external Markdown processor in the variable `markdown-command`.

By default, Markdown Mode uses the `markdown` command, that is, the original Markdown implementation, which does not supported various extensions, such as the code blocks in your example.

You need to install a Markdown processor that supports this kind of markup and set `markdown-command` accordingly.

You can use [markdown2](https://github.com/trentm/python-markdown2), for example:

```
(setq markdown-command "markdown2 -x fenced-code-blocks")
```

Comment: Looks like you're right - the fenced-code I'm using is for Github flavoured markdown. I didn't realise it wasn't part of standard markdown.